# What TCP port number does the aws cli s3 use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

When you upload or download files via aws cli, what TCP port number does it use over the internet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see on [AWS Regions and Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) that Amazon S3 supports HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443).

They are normal REST calls to a web service.